# Sms Inbox - TextView

Tags: android

Hello i am created Sms app witch shows me content of Inbox.I am using TextView but there is problem with screen.I can't see all sms but only sms of screen size.. I can't scroll down.How can i see all sms with scroll down / up? Or is it supported on TextView?
Sorry for my english i am czech .
Thanks

Source code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Mynew extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          TextView view = new TextView(this);
          Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
          Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
          String sms = "";
          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
              String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
              String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
              sms += "From :" + address  + " : " + body+"\n";         
          }
          view.setText(sms);
          setContentView(view);
      }
    }
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/row_entry"/>

/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="New.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Mynew"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the TextView with a ScrollView.

Or more likely what you want if you need to do something useful with the list : Learn about ListViews

Comment: Yes, i am tried to make this aplication with ListView, but it didn't work.Can i post here source code with listview and can you check it please?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't how it works. You can post bits of your code you don't know why they are not working. But it is your work to single out the problems and submit here only specific problems. On google you'll find lots of material and sample code on using listviews.

Comment: Yes its true but i dont know how i can fill listview by data.I will make new topic.

Comment: No, please don't. Google listview, look at sample code, use the documentation and then when you have a problem, a specific one, come back here with that specific problem.